# ASP.NET Core: Parse complex struct from URL

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have GET API method:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<TripDto> Get([FromQuery]RequestDto req)
{
    // some logic here
}
```

And RequestDto it is complex object:

```
public class RequestDto
{
    public List<SegmentDto> Segments { get; set; } = new List<SegmentDto>();
    public string SessionId { get; set; } 
}

public class SegmentDto
{
    public string Departure { get; set; }
    public string Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And when I send request:

```
http://localhost:5000/trips?Segments[0][Departure]=SIP&Segments[0][Arrival]=MOW&Segments[1][Departure]=MOW&Segments[1][Arrival]=SIP&SessionId=s1
```

in my `req` variable I see only session parameter. How I can parse complex list structure from GET request?

Comment: First option, don't. Use POST instead. Failing that, write a custom formatter which can deserialize your specific type from query string. I am guessing the default one is creating a new object for each key.

Comment: @TanveerBadar But if I create REST API my method must be GET? Because POST for creating data. Is not it?

Comment: That's kind of where adherence to REST principles breaks down in real life. Some things just don't quite fit the REST pattern. You can do as Tanveer suggested and create a custom formatter to handle your query string pattern, or you can deviate a bit from normal REST and use a POST request to accomplish this.

Comment: @mason what is custom formatter? Do you have any links with examples? Thank you

Comment: Formatter was probably the wrong word, I think IValueProvider is the proper term in ASP.NET Core. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/).

Comment: I see a lot of people really struggling to adhere to REST, despite the fact that nothing bad happens if you occasionally deviate from the normal pattern. In that case, we just call it an HTTP API and move on with our lives. Decide whether it's worth it to implement custom code to handle binding the query string as you want, or whether deviating from the typical REST principles is acceptable.

Comment: You could always rename your method to `Request` or something similar if you don't want to have a method called `Get` not be `HTTP Get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You don't need to initialize properties in classes that solely used for parsing

```
public class RequestDto
{
    public List<SegmentDto> Segments { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; } 
}
```

2) Use dot notation for objects (no need to capitalize names)

```
?segments[0].departure=SIP&segments[0].arrival=MOW&...
```

Comment: Thank for answer, it is working. Do you have any link to documentation about this feature?

Comment: You're welcome. Nope, I couldn't find anything on it.